# Error in mru internal routine: ORA-20001 / Timestamp / NULL primary Keys

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

Thanks so far guys,

I feel like I am getting further and further with your help firstly!

However, I've got another issue now when I am using the form wizard provided by oracle.

The issue I have is when following the wizard it asks to set up a primary key column, but once I have I cannot add ROWS to it.

To get an idea of what I mean here is the example:

[image: screenshot of form]

The schedule number cannot be added.

Here is the SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "MACHINE_SCHEDULE" 
   (    "SCHEDULE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
    "MACHINE_NO" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    "MACHINE_USE_DATE" DATE, 
    "START_TIME" TIMESTAMP (3) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "END_TIME" TIMESTAMP (3) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "PROCESS" VARCHAR2(164 CHAR), 
    "BATCH_NO" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    "MATERIAL_BAR_NO" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "TECHNICIAN_STAFF_NO" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "MACHINE_SCHEDULE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SCHEDULE_NUMBER") ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "MACHINE_SCHEDULE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MACHINE_SCHEDULE_CON" FOREIGN KEY ("TECHNICIAN_STAFF_NO")
      REFERENCES  "MODULE_TECHNICIAN" ("TECHNICIAN_STAFF_NO") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "MACHINE_SCHEDULE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MACHINE_SCHEDULE_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("BATCH_NO")
      REFERENCES  "BATCH" ("BATCH_NO") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "MACHINE_SCHEDULE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MACHINE_SCHEDULE_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("MATERIAL_BAR_NO")
      REFERENCES  "MATERIAL_BAR" ("MATERIAL_BAR_NO") ENABLE
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_MACHINE_SCHEDULE" 
  before insert on "MACHINE_SCHEDULE"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."SCHEDULE_INSTANT_NUMBER" is null then 
    select "MACHINE_SCHEDULE_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."SCHEDULE_INSTANT_NUMBER" from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_MACHINE_SCHEDULE" DISABLE
/
```

However, when I am trying to add rows into the table I get the error:

```
Error in mru internal routine: ORA-20001: Error in MRU: row= 1, 
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column, 
insert into "GROUP7_1"."MACHINE_SCHEDULE" ( "SCHEDULE_NUMBER", "MACHINE_NO", "MACHINE_USE_DATE", "START_TIME", "END_TIME", "PROCESS", "BATCH_NO", "MATERIAL_BAR_NO", "TECHNICIAN_STAFF_NO") 
values ( :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5, :b6, :b7, :b8, :b9)
```

Comment: I do not see a column named "SCHEDULE_INSTANT_NUMBER" in table  "MACHINE_SCHEDULE". Was the trigger generated by the form wizard?

Comment: "SCHEDULE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) It was created in the creation stage.

Comment: `SCHEDULE_NUMBER` != `SCHEDULE_INSTANT_NUMBER`: INSTANT is not in your table creation. Do you know what causes the `ORA-01438'? You know the size of your columns, and you know what data you enter. Is any of it larger than your column? What do the timestamps have to do with this? Why "Thanks so far"? Is there a post somewhere that is previous to this question (like on the OTN forums?)? Not that I mind, but if so just include the link so everybody has a better guess at what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks tom I did not realise that because of the time I had replied at. Also, I meant in the sense of the help provided in the previous questions. Also I've removed my timestmp question and created another questions :D